# Scala: mock Hadoop File System

Tags: scala, testing, hadoop, mocking, hdfs

I need to mock (with scalamock 4.4.0/scalatest 3.2.9) the behaviour of Hadoop file system. I found out, that I can't mock it directly, so I'm trying to get around this problem.

On the first, try I created wrapper (in the scope of main logic):

```
 class HadoopFsWrapper(path: Path)(implicit fs: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem) {
      def listStatus(path) = fs.listStatus(path)
 }

 class HadoopService(path: Path)(implicit val fs: HadoopFsWrapper){
       def someLogic() = fs.listStatus(path)
 }
```

I declare this class both in main and test code with defining of implicit HadoopFsWrapper.

```
 implicit val fs = mock[HadoopFsWrapper]

 val hs = HadoopService(path)
 // other test logic
```

And this done well.

But I don't think, its a good idea to modify main code for test purpose.
Other way I considered is to create wrapper only in test scope and apply some kind of "decorator" to deceive HadoopService, which expects FileSystem to be defined in main scope:

```
 // only in test scope
 class HadoopFsWrapper(path: Path) extends org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem {
      def listStatus(path) = listStatus(path)
      // dummies for implemented FileSystem-methods
 }
 object HadoopFsWrapper {
     def apply(): org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem = new HadoopFsWrapper
 }

 // main logic
 class HadoopService(path: Path)(implicit val fs: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem){
       def someLogic() = fs.listStatus(path)
 }
```

But when I'm trying to mock HadoopFsWrapper it's defined as null.

Comment: I don't know the details of Hadoop API but I would question the need to mock it in the 1st place. You can use Hadoop API on "regular files" for your tests most of the time.

Comment: The reason of mocking Hadoop Fs is that I need to test the processing of files with specific large size: more than 2 Gb. Will I succeed to place in test-resources of project regular files with a such size?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with modifying code to make it testable in general. Also, I have no idea what the last sentence in your question means. I don't see much of a difference between your first and second snippets (other than a huge unnecessary boilerplate in the latter).

Comment: Dima, the main difference is that in first snippet Wrapper declared with FileSystem as implicit argument,  at that time in second case Wrapper extends FileSystem. In second snipped I illustrated, how I tried to "plant" a Wrapper to HadoopService in test scope under guise of FileSystem (see, that apply method in companion object returns)

Comment: @Jelly what do you aim to test. How mocking Hadoop API will help in testing specific stuff related to big files? If this really is a case to test, look's more like a kind of integration test rather than unit test. But again hard to be very affirmative without more context.

Comment: Your local filesystem can handle 2GB files on its own. Therefore, you can use Hadoop's existing local file handler, and use Junit temporary directory rule, for example (or whatever scalatest offers).

Comment: Gaël J, the task is to test calculation of Spark-partitions number, based on the size of file in specified hdfs-directory. Such 2Gb must return 24 partitions, 5 Gb -> 42, ect.  Partitions number is used for further Spark operations (for example read and write with repartition()  option).

Comment: What's the code that does this logic? I've a feeling that you could test this more high level and trust Hadoop for the actual files stuff but not re-test Hadoop.

Comment: Gaël, may be you are right